# Estimate of an exponential sum involving the Von Mangoldt function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.
Define
$$
S(\alpha) = \sum_{1 \leq n \leq N} \Lambda(n) e^{2 \pi i f(n) \alpha}.
$$
I was wondering how does one obtain that
$$
\left( \int_0^1 S(\alpha) \ d \alpha \right)^2 \leq (\log N)^2 \ T(N),
$$
where $T(N)$ is the number of $(n,n') \in [1,N]^2$ such that $f(n) = f(n')$? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have $$\left|\int_{0}^{1}S\left(\alpha\right)d\alpha\right|^{2}\leq\int_{0}^{1}\left|S\left(\alpha\right)\right|^{2}d\alpha=\sum_{n\leq N}\Lambda\left(n\right)\sum_{n'\leq N}\Lambda\left(n'\right)\int_{0}^{1}e^{2\pi i\left(f\left(n\right)-f\left(n'\right)\right)\alpha}d\alpha
 $$ (note that we have to take the modulus because we are working with complex numbers). We have $f\in\mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]
 $, so by the orthogonality of the exponential function, i.e. $$\int_{0}^{1}e^{2\pi i\left(f\left(n\right)-f\left(n'\right)\right)\alpha}d\alpha=\begin{cases}
1, & f\left(n\right)=f\left(n'\right)\\
0, & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
 $$ we have $$\left|\int_{0}^{1}S\left(\alpha\right)d\alpha\right|^{2}\leq\sum_{n\leq N}\Lambda\left(n\right)\sum_{\underset{{\scriptstyle f\left(n\right)=f\left(n'\right)}}{n'\leq N}}\Lambda\left(n'\right)\leq\log^{2}\left(N\right)T\left(N\right)
 $$ by the definition of the Von Mangoltd function.

Comment: Could you possibly explain how you obtained the very last inequality by any chance? Thank you!

Comment: The Von Mangoldt function is defined $\Lambda\left(n\right)=\log\left(p\right)$ if $n=p^{k}$ for some $k\geq1$ and $0$ otherwise. Then each sum is smaller than the max (in this case $\log\left(N\right)$) multiplied by the number of the addends, i.e. $T\left(N\right)$.